# Problems creating a categorical histogram in Bokeh and Pandas

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to produce a simple histogram of categorical data with the following code

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

# some fake categories and count data
counts = pd.Series({'Cat0':1599, 'Cat1':1357, 'Cat2':671, 
                    'Cat3':610, 'Cat4':446, 'Cat5':210})

# pull out the categories from the index
cats = list(counts.keys())

plt = figure(x_range=cats)
plt.vbar(cats, top=list(counts.values), width=2, line_color='green')
show(plt)
```

but instead of a plot I get

`Javascript error adding output!
Error: Error rendering Bokeh model: could not find tag with id: e7346df5-7d3d-4f34-92e2-9e59eb36ec41
See your browser Javascript console for more details.`

Is this a bug or have I specified something wrong?

I am using Firefox 54.0 running on Ubuntu (kernel 4.10.0).  Other Bokeh plots run without a problem.  I am outputting them inline to a Jupyter notebook.
Bokeh is bokeh-0.12.4-py3.6.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is causing the problem, but re-executing

`from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook`

and re-running

`output_notebook()`

solves the problem and plots again show in the notebook.

Comment: Both Bokeh and the notebook are big, complex, multi-runtime pieces of software. Getting them to play well together has been a big challenge. That said, I think things have been reasonably stable for some time, after a round of work specifically aimed to improve notebook integration late last year. I would recommend upgrading if possible. The latest version is `0.12.7`